# Is the system in equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, non-equilibrium

If the time derivative of the Liapunov functional related to free energy of my system is zero, can I say my system is in chemical *equilibrium*?

Comment: Could you give some details on how you've actually constructed a Lyapunov function for the free energy?

Comment: @lemon, my background is a extended Cahn-Hilliard equation, in which a Liapunov functional is defined. This free energy consists of gravitational or other body forces potential and surface energy.The deriving process is very complicated. For your information, I recommend a [paper](http://www.wikiupload.com/GV3CNDSU0LUI7RW) to you.